# C++ simplest way of loading "irregular" data from file

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a data file (representing an adjacency lists) that I would like to load as a `std::vector< std::list<int> >`.

```
1 2 4
0 2
0 1

0
```

What is the cleanest way to do that in C++ / C++11?

---

Here is a crappy try, that doesn't work for blank lines…

```
vector< list<int> > data;
ifstream file("data.dat");
char foo;

while(file >> foo){
    file.unget();
    list<int> mylist;
    while( file.get() != '\n'){
        file.unget();
        int n;
        file >> n;
        mylist.push_back(n);
        cout << n;
    }
    data.push_back(mylist);
}

file.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read line by line and parse that into lists:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line);) {
    std::istringstream str(line);
    data.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<int>(str), std::istream_iterator<int>{});
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the parsing syntax!

Comment: @styko It is not really *the* parsing syntax (there are also other ways to do this), but the stream iterators are often a good tool for parsing a stream without having to write much code.

Comment: I still have a compilation error: `no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::list<int> >::emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<int>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: use getline:

```
std::string line
std::getline(file, line);
```

Then you could put this into a stringstream

```
std::stringstream s;
s.str(line);
```

Then insert them into the list

```
std::list<int>& list = data[lineNumber];
int num = 0;
while (s >> num)
    list.emplace_back(num);
```